# Using webworker inside electron app which use puppeteer

Tags: node.js, electron, puppeteer, web-worker, worker

I read [web workers API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) and [puppeteer docs about worker](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.16.0&show=api-workerevaluatehandlepagefunction-args). Now I'm trying to use worker within my electron app which use puppeteer webdriver. App was generated with [vue-electron](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) boileplate. I want to use worker in node side of electron application.

So far I tried like they show in MDN:

```
const Worker = require('worker_threads');
console.log(Worker);
```

this cause error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'worker_threads'

I made sure I'm using latest node version by `node -v` in terminal and I am, version is `v12.3.1`.

Next I tried to dig something in nodejs / help on github I found [this](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/1498) where they suggest to use `--experimental-worker`. So I did:

```
"dev": "node --experimental-worker .electron-vue/dev-runner.js",
```

Still same error. Next I tried to find something in `electron` issuses on github and I found [this topic](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16611) where they suggest to set environment variable of `NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-worker`. So I did (windows 10):

[image]

(sorry about polish). Error is still same. I can't find any more tips in network. I definitely need your help guys.

I really want to try this worker_threads because every 300ms I'm getting very big (over 200k elements) array from one of pages and I'm performing filters on this array which cause browser "lags".

Environment:

- Windows 10

Comment: “I'm a bit confused of how to combine this puppeteer implementation of worker and native NodeJS web worker.” – I’m not sure you are meant to combine these. Either you use a worker in node or you use one in the browser (which can be controlled using puppeteer API)…

Comment: Ahh, that explain a bit, thank you. Anyway currently I'm trying to use woker in node. That's why I `require` it. Do you have some tip a bit this error `Error: Cannot find module 'worker_threads'`?

Comment: I deleted this sentence from question as it's clearly not related to issue.

Comment: I don’t have much experience with electron but try using `electron --js-flags="--experimental-worker"` as seen [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15748#issuecomment-447050804).

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately :(

Comment: I think the `"dev": "node --experimental-worker .electron-vue/dev-runner.js"` is only used to start a “wrapper” of some sorts that starts the real electron app. Passing the flags to that won’t help, you need to figure out where vue-electron actually launches electron and pass flags there.

Comment: Check the electron version in your project. You might be using an older version of electron which in-turn might have an older version of node ( below v10 ), where worker threads are not supported.

Comment: @Raphael Schweikert You might be right I'll investigate it in a second. @Shobhit Chittora `process.versions.electron` in electron window console tab is giving `"2.0.17"`

Comment: @ShobhitChittora what do you mean by v10? Currently latest version as I checked second ago is v5.x

Comment: I meant the version of node which ships with electron might be older. Check this file -> https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v2.0.8/.node-version.

Also how does your `process.versions` look like. Can you post it in the question?

Comment: In my `node_modules/electron` there is no .node-version file but there is package.json in which `"dependencies": {"@types/node": "^8.0.24",`. My `process.versions` is: https://i.imgur.com/1BFBQnE.png . So I think you spot the issue because the node version there, is `8.9.3` and they added worker in `10.5`. Now the question is how to update it. Additionally @Raphael Schweikert in dev-runner.js I found array `var args = ['--inspect=5858',` which contain args which are then passed to command which really start electron. So it works similiar to something like query building.

Comment: @ShobhitChittora so I just have to run `npm i -D electron@latest`. You can add answer.

Comment: Thanks @BT101. You can mark the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the `Worker Thread API` just shipped with node versions above `v10`. The version you're using ( electron 2.x ) ships with node v8.x which doesn't have the feature shipped.